# Java Program to Print out the max, min, and average of three user inputted numbers

Tags: java

Am I on the right track?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Practice_8_1 {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static int max (int x, int y, int z){
  int maximum = 0;
  if (x > y && x > z){
     return x;
     } else if (y > z && y > x){
        return y;
       else {
        return z;
  }

  public static int min (int x, int y, int z){
  //code for min
  }  
  public static int average (int x, int y, int z){
  //code for average 
   } 
  }
}
```

what exactly goes in the main method? I have to do this using methods.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int min (int x, int y, int z) {
  int Min =  (y>x)?x:y;
  Min = (z>Min)?Min:z;
  return Min;
} 

public static int max (int x, int y, int z) {
  int Max =  (y>x)?y:x;
  Max = (z>Max)?z:Max;
  return Max;
} 

public static int average (int x, int y, int z) {
  return (x+y+z)/3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't write the definition of a method inside another method; instead, you would *call* those methods from inside of `main`.  (And you declare `maximum` in `max`, but never use it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to put numbers in it and then use `Arrays.sort(array)` to sort members of this array from lowest to highest. It means that on the first index will be lowest number.
It could be easier than those three methods.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[]numbers = new int[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        System.out.println("Type a number:");
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    }
    // this sorts the array members from lowest to highest
    Arrays.sort(numbers);

    System.out.println("Lowest number is " + numbers[0]);
    System.out.println("Middle number is " + numbers[1]);
    System.out.println("Highest number is " + numbers[2]);
}   
}
```

If you have to use method, you can sort that Array in static method.

```
public static int[] sortNumbers(int[] numbers) {

    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    return numbers;
}
```

and in the main method instead using `Arrays.sort(numbers)`use

`numbers = sortNumbers(numbers);`